The Great [tag-cleanup-request] status-tag cleanup of 2024
Following on from the Great CM status tag cleanup of 2024, we lost our "status-planned" tracking of ongoing cleanup tasks. That's because the planned tag is now considered a process tag, used by CMs to keep track of community requests that SE is currently handling.
We've pondered the introduction of a new set of "status"-style tags: Pondering mod status tags. Instead, I propose that we should do our own status-tag cleanup, and mark all finished cleanups as status-completed or status-declined. This will give us basically the inverse of a 'planned' tag: anything WITHOUT the completed or declined tags should be fair game to be worked on. Plus, 'completed and 'declined' are considered outcome tags by CMs, and therefore won't interfere with their use of process tags.
We currently have 113 questions tagged [tag-cleanup-request] -[status-completed] -[status-declined]. I've gone through all of them and listed the completed ones below. Can the mods please mark them status-completed, and the ones that the community have deemed not needed as status-declined?
These are the status-completed ones:

Are we [licensed] for all this? (Main proposed synonym was created, others discussed and not needed)  status-completed

Is there any difference between the tags "windows-server-2003" and "windows-2003-server"? status-completed

aria2 vs. aria2c? status-completed

Send out [newsletters] status-completed

Don't give us static about deleting [dynamic] status-completed

Burninate or clean up the tag [dual] status-completed

Time up on the [trial]? status-completed

Skip the [skipping] tag? status-completed

Get rid of Microsoft tag status-completed - Can you also edit the duplicate list to add: Consider blocklisting the [microsoft] tag? please? status-completed

Drop kick [dropout] status-completed

Pummel [panel]? status-completed

Unsynonomize [synaptic] and [synaptics] status-completed

The theory tag may be redundant status-completed

Pew Pew the Laser Tag status-completed

Archive the outlook-archive status-completed

Time to change [pop] flavor(s) status-completed

Can we [design] a better tag? status-completed

We're not a bank, get rid of [audit] (or replace it with less ambiguous tags) status-completed

Let's expel [native] status-completed

Cleanup up [organization] tag status-completed

Glitch tag cleanup now completed status-completed

Options tag cleanup now completed status-completed

Sonicwall: Is it a manufacturer tag? status-completed

Possible Tag Merge: [toshiba-satellite] into [toshiba-laptop] status-completed

tag cleanup: [editor] status-completed

Let's dellete [dell] status-completed

Split the [manual] tag status-completed

Clear up the [clear] tag status-completed

Document or shred [manual]? status-completed

Tag cleanup: Delete / merge [function] tag status-completed


These can be status-declined. I've included individual reasons as to why:

Take away the chinese tag - community members make a good argument for keeping individual language tags separate (Further reading: Are languages too localized?)
I speak [spanish], and [english] too… - duplicate of above
Deprecate product version preview tags - just use new version tag straight away - OS preview tags are kept for questions specific to preview/pre-release/beta versions of OSs.
Remove [zip-drive] tag? - zip-drive is an adequate tag
Burninate the [ssid] tag - ssid is a meaningful tag

TO DO

The next [selection] for burnination

Rename Tag: [attachments] into [email-attachments] - cleanup warranted, rename not. Better to use a new question to organise the cleanup.



Note the list here is very specific to tags that were 100% removed, synonymised, or definitively declined. There are plenty more requests that are in a half-resolved state, aren't clear-cut, ask too many things, or are just discussions about tags without a clear 'request'. I'm not attempting to address those here.

So... what do I tag this? :D

@JourneymanGeek when it's done, you can tag it status-completed

We appreciate the assist.  I've retagged everything that I felt comfortable retagging, which is pretty much all but 2 posts.
I didn't label the status-declined posts cause I did them at a sitting, and it felt wierd to decline a request we carried out. They're reviewed and actioned tho.
There's 2 posts that needed more attention before completion so I've chosen to label them as to do, rather than taking action. They're a bit more work and we can revisit these in future.

Thanks for your efforts! Much appreciated
